# Stupid error creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What am I missing.  I have researched but I am getting this error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Create_User, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Here is the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Create_User] 
    -- variables from site for new user create
    @lg_ID varchar(50),
    @lg_PW nchar(10),
    @locked int,
    @agreed int
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.userLogin
          (LoginID, password, locked, agreed) 
     VALUES 
          (@lg_ID, @lg_PW, @locked = 0, @agreed = 0) 
END
```

Comment: You can't say @locked = 0 in the VALUES section. Do that outside the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Before the INSERT statement, set parameter values, ex.

```
SET @locked = 0
SET @agreed = 0
...
```

You must also remove the assigmnents in VALUES, ex.

```
VALUES 
      ( 
        @lg_ID,
        @lg_PW,
        @locked,
        @agreed            
      )
```

Comment: How does this help? The incoming parameter is required. Perhaps the intention is to add `= 0` to the parameter list to make those parameters optional, but blindly setting them to 0 would only make sense if the parameters didn't belong there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want 0 as the default value for both @locked and @agreed. Instead of having @locked = 0 try `isnull(@locked, 0)`. isnull replaces null values with a specified replacement value.

Additionally, you can create default values for stored procedure parameters in this manner:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Create_User] 
    -- variables from site for new user create
    @lg_ID varchar(50),
    @lg_PW nchar(10),
    @locked int = 0,
    @agreed int = 0

AS
```

Comment: Gacias` That worked perfectly.  Here is my final SP:  Thanks         ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Create_User] 
 -- variables from site for new user create
 @lg_ID varchar(50),
 @lg_PW nchar(10),
 @locked int = 1, --set default value to account ready
 @agreed int = 0 --set value to account locked until the waiver has been signed
 
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.userLogin(LoginID, password, locked, agreed) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @lg_ID,
            @lg_PW,
            @locked,
            @agreed            
          ) 

END